# How to find max value from each group and display their information when using "group by"

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, i create a table about people contribue to 2 campaigns

```
+-------------------------------------+
| ID    Name   Campaign  Amount (USD) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1      A         1             10   |
| 2      B         1             5    |
| 3      C         2             7    |
| 4      D         2             9    |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Task: For each campaign, find the person (Name, ID) who contribute the most to

Expected result is

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|     Campaign          Name           ID |
+-----------------------------------------+
|     1                 A              1  |
|     2                 D              4  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I used "group by Campaign" but the result have 2 columns "Campagin" and "max value" when I need "Name" and "ID"

Thanks for your help.
Edited: I fix some values, really sorry

Comment: You ID and campaign column in input table, does it have correct values?

Comment: I edited, sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can use analytic functions for this:

```
select name, id, amount
from (select t.*, max(amount) over (partition by campaign) as max_amount
      from t
     ) t
where amount = max_amount;
```

Comment: all campaign have distinct value. How will your query work?

Comment: sorry for the data, i will fix it

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by giving a rank/row_number partiton by `campaign` and order by descending order of `amount`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [num] = dense_rank() over(
        partition by [Campaign]
        order by [Amount] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [Campaign], [Name], [ID]
from cte
where [num] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next query:-

```
 SELECT Campaign  ,  Name  ,    ID 
 FROM (
       SELECT Campaign  ,  Name  ,    ID , MAX (Amount)
         FROM MyTable
       GROUP BY Campaign , Name , ID
 ) temp;
```

Comment: Btw, i can not group a statement by using "()", always got this error

Comment: Try the corrected version (missing alias for the internal select).

Answer (score 0):

**Simply** use `Where` Clause with the `max` of amount `group by` Campaign:-

As following generic code:-

```
select a,  b , c
from tablename
where d in
(
    select  max(d) 
    from tablename
    group by a
)
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create table #MyTable (ID int , Name char(1), Campaign int , Amount int)
go

insert into #MyTable values (1,'A',1,10)
insert into #MyTable values (2,'B',1,5)
insert into #MyTable values (3,'C',2,7)
insert into #MyTable values (4,'D',2,9)
go

select Campaign,  Name , ID
from #MyTable
where Amount in
(
    select  max(Amount) 
    from #MyTable
    group by Campaign
) 

drop table #MyTable
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Comment: Wrong you need to correlate the sub-query. It could bring wrong results

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code for the same

```
SELECT * 
FROM #MyTable T
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(1) record 
    FROM #MyTable T1
    where t.Campaign = t1.Campaign
    and t.amount < t1.amount
)E
where E.record = 0
```